# Как отключить (и главное что именно) оптимизацию, для кусочка кода, или обойти таковую. GCC

Tags: оптимизация, gcc, x86, x86-64

Доброго времени суторк.
Имею такой код.

```
dburl = db_short_url_find( conf, &(RQ) );
if( dburl == NULL )
{
    hash = ngx_hash_strlow( RQ.data, RQ.data, RQ.len);
    dburl = ngx_hash_find(&conf->short_url_hash, hash, RQ.data, RQ.len);        
    /*
     if not found, use {RQ}
     */       
    if( NULL == dburl )  
    {
        dburl = &(RQ);
    }             
}
```

во втором if-е условие всегда выполняется, даже когда (я сам это видел) bdurl уже не равен NULL, видимо оптимизация. То же самое происходит если if вынести наружу (изначально так и было)и поставить после первого if-а. dburl == NULL или NULL == dburl тоже не важно.

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("что-нить")   
....
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Возможно, как вариант. Но...во-первых функция большая, и не хотелось бы ее всю лишать оптимизации, а во-вторых какая опция отвечает за "такую оптимизацию"??
В общем нужна либо правильная прагма, желательно на кусочек кода, либо хитрость, чтоб обойти "умный" компилятор...буду рад любым конструктивным идеям.

Comment: Оптимизация никогда не может сделать такой код не рабочим, если конечно это правильная оптимизация. Скорее всего просто у вас указатель dburl действительно всегда NULL, вы можете его до проверки if вывести на консоль (printf или cout) и посмотреть чему он действительно равен. Кроме того надёжный способ в общем случае запретить оптимизацию переменной это добавить к ней в объявлении модификатор `volatile`.

Comment: ну да, конечно, не может...по шагам прошел, значение посмотрел, следующий шаг и опа! [вот, можно посмотреть] (http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1710/50/aae2fe7539e9.png) всплывающее сообщение, показывает значение переменной. красная полоса, указатель прграммного счетчика. а вот на счет volatile, это правильно...это я подзабыл...спасибо

Comment: Как раз таки расчитывать на показания отладчика не всегда верно, как раз отладчику мешает оптимизация и он иногда показывает не верные значения. Самый надёжный способ это вывести значение куда-то, либо на консоль, либо в файл, либо сообщением на экран, зависит от того куда может выводить ваша программа. Просто оптимизатор никогда не может нарушить логику работы программы, всегда оптимизация расчитана на то что логика будет не уничтожена. Кстати volatile пробовали ставить? Я уверен если вы в лог или консоль выведете то окажется что там 0.

Comment: Также вполне возможно что отладчик показывает не верно что исполнение зашло в тело if, если там в dburl не ноль, то отладчик может показывать что в тело зашли когда на самом деле не зашли. Чтобы точно убедиться поставьте до if вывод значения dburl на консоль или лог, а в теле if поставьте сообщение какое-то что мол зашли в тело. Вывод на консоль или в файл никогда не оптимизируется и вы точно увидите правду.

Comment: Кстати, с voatile попробовал, - та же фигня. Вот теперь, точно странно. А по-поводу отладчика, с одной стороны согласен, но я же не просто указатель вижу. указатель указывает на найденный элемент данных. т.е. все как надо, только переход в "нетуда". попробую вывод на консоль организовать.

Comment: `db_short_url_find()` и `ngx_hash_find()` внешние функции или компилятор видит их код?

Comment: в тупую пересоздал проект. пересобрал. и все стало нормально. в общем не знаю что ему не хватало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тупую пересоздал проект. Пересобрал. И все заработало. Так и не понял что было.

Comment: Как что? Корявый скрипт сборки и отладчик который не умеет или не настроен контролировать корректность исходников. Вы думаете что отлаживаете актуальный код - а на самом деле отлаживается код трехдневной давности.